# Sorting Data using numpy for loop cycle range error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
Vetor_nascer=[]
Vetor_ocasso=[]
cos=ang_zenital_cos(lat, long, dj, horas)
cos=cos[indices_hora_i]
for i in range(len(indices_hora_i)):
    if cos[i]<0 and cos[i+1]>0:
        Vetor_nascer=np.append(Vetor_nascer,indices_hora_i[i])
    elif cos[i]>0 and cos[i+1]<0:
        Vetor_ocasso=np.append(Vetor_ocasso,indices_hora_i[i])
```

Hey guys how can i make this not return the error out of bound
I m trying make vector so i can index a specific set of data i i need to make mark when cos(1)=- and cos(2)=+
How can i do to so it doesnt give me a error?

Comment: How do you want to deal with the last element in `cos`

Answer (score 1):

Your loop tries to access out of bound of array, you can loop one time less:

```
for i in range(len(indices_hora_i)-1):
    if cos[i]<0 and cos[i+1]>0:
        Vetor_nascer=np.append(Vetor_nascer,indices_hora_i[i])
    elif cos[i]>0 and cos[i+1]<0:
        Vetor_ocasso=np.append(Vetor_ocasso,indices_hora_i[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by using reverse indexing

So i knew my data had the size 29760 so i just wrote instead it worked. (i just dont know if there is a faster solution for the overall cycle)

```
 cos[i]<0 and cos[i-29759]>0:
```

Comment: this will check last item with first item. Is that what you are trying to do with last item?